# Merge coverage for Sonarqube with istabuljs/nyc

Tags: node.js, typescript, sonarqube

I have a typescript project that goes through a Jenkins pipeline and does all the functional tests in parallel (after building the main container). At the end of the pipeline - we create code coverage check and then ship the result out to sonarqube.

here is my package.json:

```
"test": "npm run test:unit && npm run test:component && npm run test:functional",
"test:component": "mocha --reporter mocha-sonarqube-reporter --reporter-options output=tests/coverage/component/test-xcomponent.xml --recursive -r ts-node/register tests/component/*.ts",
"test:functional": "mocha --reporter mocha-sonarqube-reporter --reporter-options output=tests/coverage/functional/test-xfunctional.xml --recursive -r ts-node/register tests/functional/*.ts",
"test:unit": "mocha --reporter mocha-sonarqube-reporter --reporter-options output=tests/coverage/unit/test-xunit.xml --recursive -r ts-node/register tests/unit/*.ts",
"test:unit:nosq": "mocha --recursive -r ts-node/register tests/unit/*.ts",
"lint": "tslint -t verbose --project tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
"cover": "nyc --report-dir tests/coverage/all npm run test",
"cover:unit": "nyc --report-dir tests/coverage/unit npm run test:unit",
"cover:functional": "nyc --report-dir tests/coverage/functional -x 'app/repositories' -x 'app/entities' -x 'app/utils' --no-clean npm run test:functional"
```

my sonar-project.properties is like the following:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/*.spec.ts,app/entities/**,dependency-check-report/*,tests/coverage/**/*
sonar.tests=tests
sonar.test.inclusions=tests/**/*
sonar.ts.tslintconfigpath=tslint.json
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=tests/coverage/all/lcov.info
```

I have two problems with this setup:

- I cannot seem to find a way to merge the different coverage files. I have checked the official istanbuljs/nyc GitHub and it states that it can combine via `nyc merge` command however the output is .json and sonarqube requires xml. I am stuck with half my code coverage since I'm only shipping out one file out and not the combine file.
- I currently have code smell errors from the tests/coverage/all folder as it considered missing fonts from the generated coverage is being missing. I have excluded that folder in the `sonar-project.properties` file and I've included it in the .gitignore too but sonarqube is still reporting it as code small.

Comment: SonarQube does not require xml files for JS coverage, it requires **lcov**: [JavaScript Coverage Results Import](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Coverage+Results+Import)

Comment: @zero298 yes im aware but im not familiar with what is the difference and I've already included it my properties: as shown above: sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=tests/coverage/all/lcov.info

Comment: `nyc report --reporter=lcov --report-dir=.nyc_coverage` should take every JSON coverage file in `.nyc_output` and covert it to a singular lcov file made up of all the JSON reports in the directory at the time of running.  Can you try that and see if that gives you a good report?  You can add `--reporter=text` as well to get both an lcov and an immediate text output for sanity.

Comment: hey @zero298 correct syntax: `nyc --reporter lcov --reporter text --report-dir .nyc_coverage report` and I added it after my cover test: so `nyc npm run test && nyc --reporter lcov --reporter text --report-dir .nyc_coverage report` and I set the sonarqube property to that path. If you want the points - please write as a solution. tks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SonarQube does not require XML files for JavaScript coverage, it requires the report to be in **lcov** format.  Please see SonarQube's documentation: [JavaScript Coverage Results Import](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Coverage+Results+Import).

In order to generate this lcov report, you can do the following:

1. Put all of your JSON coverage data (what the browser/harness writes the `__coverage__` global to) in a directory, the default is `.nyc_output`
2. Run the command `nyc report --reporter=lcov --report-dir=.nyc_coverage`
3. This tells `nyc` that you want to generate a report using all the files in the directory specified by `--report-dir` (`.nyc_coverage` in this case) and that you want the report in the format specified by `--reporter` (`lcov` in this case)
4. `nyc` will create a folder (`.nyc_output` by default) and write the lcov file there

If you would like, you can also add extra reporters for sanity.  I usually add `--reporter=text` so that it will print out the coverage as well.

So your final command might be:

```
nyc report \
  --reporter=lcov \
  --reporter=text \
  --report-dir=.nyc_coverage
```

The `=` are optional and the command arguments can precede the sub-command, so you can also run the command that you noted:

```
nyc --reporter lcov --reporter text --report-dir .nyc_coverage report
```

Additionally, you tell SonarQube where the report is by specifying it on command line:

```
sonar-scanner \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=whatever \
  -Dsonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
```

Or you can set it in the project settings:

```
Project -> Administration -> JavaScript -> Tests and Coverage -> LCOV Files
```

Comment: excellent - thanks for the complete answer (actually for some reason the equal sign was telling about too many argument weird)